# Loading Devise sign up/sign in forms via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I'm trying to render out my sign up/sign in forms which I've created using devise 2.2.0 against my Member model, using AJAX. Now, instead of modifying the original devise SessionsController, in order to return format.js, I have created a new controller which is only meant to render out the 'devise/sessions/new' template (note that format.html is simply for debugging purposes) - see code below:

```
class SessionsAjaxController < ApplicationController
def new
    @member = Member.new
    respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render :template => 'devise/sessions/new', :locals =>  {  :resource => @member,  :resource_name => Member } }                       
            format.js  { render :template => 'devise/sessions/new',  :layout => false, :locals =>  {  :resource => @member,  :resource_name => Member} }                          
    end  
end
```

I am getting the following error, either when trying to go directly to '/sessions_ajax/new' or loading from AJAX:

```
undefined method `email' for #<Class:0x410e608>
```

and the error points to "around line 11" in new.html.erb

```
10: <%= f.label :email, "EMAIL" %><br />    
11: <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>
```

I am passing resource and resource_name correctly as :locals, so I don't quite understand what the heck I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit from `Devise::SessionsController`.